# Upload file with webdriver (C#) works in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm able to upload a file in Firefox using Selenium Webdriver C# but the same code doesn't work for IE. I am using IE11 and the latest IEDriverServer 3.6.0.
I have been looking all over internet for a solution but nothing works. I will appreciate any help here

This is my code below. And I am wondering if there is a javascript way of doing this?

```
public UploadPage HTUpload(string filePath = "C:\\\\Users\\\\Me\\\\Desktop\\\\Capture.JPG")
    {
        int retryCount = 0;
        while (retryCount < Constants.RETRY_COUNT)
        {
            try
            {
                _driver.FindElement(By.Name("files[]")).SendKeys(filePath);
                return this;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (ex is WebDriverTimeoutException || ex is TimeoutException)
            {
                retryCount++;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
```

```html
<div class="fileupload">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                        <span>Add files...</span>
                        <input name="files[]"  multiple="multiple" type="file"/>
                    </span>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start" name="btnupload">
                      
                        <span>Start upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel" name="btncancel">
                      
                        <span>Cancel upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                       
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" />
                    <!-- The global file processing state -->
                    <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you share HTML for upload button?

Comment: @KuldeepKamune Thanks for your response. I have updated the main post with my htlm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like your file path is incorrect. You have set path as

```
filePath = "C:\\\\Users\\\\Me\\\\Desktop\\\\Capture.JPG"
```

When you set these path in SendKeys(), its became like:

```
filePath = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Capture.JPG"
```

which is invalid path (as i tried the same path & it throw invalid path error)

Could you please update your file path as & try again:

```
filePath = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Capture.JPG"
```

I think,it should work, please try and let me know if it work. If any error throw, please post error for analysis.

And as you ask for Javascript code, please give below code try:

```
String script = "document.getElementById('files[]').value='" + "C:\\\\Users\\\\Me\\\\Desktop\\\\Capture.JPG" + "';";
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script);
```